# Bottom margin on the page following \newgeometry not respected

Tags: margins

I make a document in booklet format and I would like the first page to be centered.

I have used the twoside argument for the geometry package.
When I redefine the geometry for the title page, it worked as excepted but on the next page the bottom margin isn't respected.

There is my MWC :

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, twoside, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}           
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \newgeometry{left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm}
            \Huge{test} 
        \restoregeometry
    \end{titlepage}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

And there is a picture of the following page, even the page number is in the wrong place.

[image: Bottom of the page following newgeometry]

And there a picture of the other page which are as expected

[image]

Have you any idea where that can come from ? Thanks

Comment: unrelated but size commands do not take an argument, use `\Huge test ` not `\Huge{test} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the geometry changes outside the titlepage environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, twoside, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm}

\begin{titlepage}
 \Huge test
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry

\lipsum
\end{document}
```